# After sorting table, The alternate row color in table row is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

i am using a table with alternate row color and the same table has sorting functionality with jquery.tablesorter.js. as follow.

css can be applied for alternative row like.

```
              $("tr:even",$(this)).css({'backgroundColor':'#ffffff'});
              $("tr:odd",$(this)).css({'backgroundColor':'#ebf0f5'});
```

sorting can be done by

```
             function sortTable(tableID)
                {
                     $("#"+tableID).tablesorter();      
                }
```

First time alternative row color works fine.

But When I sort the records the format has been changed. and alternative row color is not working.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How do you color the rows? if you're using CSS's :nth-child(odd/even), it should be ok.

Comment: The last time I did some table sorting was a while ago, but from what I remember whichever JQuery sort routine I used did the alternate colours automatically. Perhaps if you post some of your HTML/CSS/JS?

Comment: hi i am using . $("tr:even",$(this)).css({'backgroundColor':'#ffffff'});
     $("tr:odd",$(this)).css({'backgroundColor':'#ebf0f5'});

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the zebra widget:

```
$("table").tablesorter({widgets: ['zebra']})
```

Comment: Thanx Man, It's work well. But before use **$("table").tablesorter({widgets: ['zebra']})** , You needs to empty the css then only chages are affected.                                    Like this **$("tr:even",$(this)).css({'backgroundColor':''});
    $("tr:odd",$(this)).css({'backgroundColor':''});**

Answer (score 3):

after sort completed you can run this jquery code:

```
$("table <make it more specific!>").find("tr").removeClass("alt").filter(":odd").addClass("alt");
```

Here is the [jsFiddler code](http://jsfiddle.net/8NvES/14/).

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$('#table').tablesorter({
    widgets     : ['zebra'],
    widgetZebra : {
        css: ['your_even_css_class_name', 'your_odd_css_class_name']
    }
});
```

And remove this:

```
$("tr:even",$(this)).css({'backgroundColor':'#ffffff'});
$("tr:odd",$(this)).css({'backgroundColor':'#ebf0f5'});
```

Comment: $('#table').tablesorter({   
        widgetZebra : {
            css: ['your_even_css_class_name', 'your_odd_css_class_name']
        }
    });